# Error in Linq Query when using anonymous return on List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query, where I want to return the total number of each StatusType as a list.

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<IList<(StatusType StatusType, int Count)>>> GetSummaryByStatusTypeAsync()
    {
        Func<Task<IList<(StatusType StatusType, int Count)>>> func = async () =>
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory())
            {
                var items = (await context.ToListAsync<Job>(x => x
                                .Include(y => y.Status)))
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Status.StatusType)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                StatusType = x.Key,
                                Count = x.Count()
                            }).ToList();

                return items;
            }
        };

        return await this.ExecuteAsync(func);
    }
```

However, I get the errors;

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: Core.StatusType
> StatusType, int Count>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<(Core.StatusType StatusType, int
> Count)>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> CS4010    Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
> 'Task<IList<(StatusType StatusType, int Count)>>'. An async lambda
> expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are
> convertible to 'Task<IList<(StatusType StatusType, int Count)>>'.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit, you are trying to return an anonymous type when the function expects a tuple.

Comment: In your `Select()`, your're using anonymous type while the method signature claims that you need to return a `ValueTuple<StatusType, int>`. Use `x => (x.Key, x.Count())` instead.

Comment: I also don't understand why you are creating this inline `Func`, that's really peculiar.

Comment: LINQ doesn't have async operations, or `Include`. Are you using EF Core? DbContext doesn't have a `ToListAsync` nor does it need one - it's a Unit-of-Work for very specific entities, not a database model or connection. The cause for the problem is hidden in methods you haven't posted, eg `ExecuteAsync`, that `ToListAsync` and `_contextFactory`

Comment: @Heinzi, You're right. Fixed.

Comment: You can return a tuple instead of an anonymous type with `.Select(x=>(x.Key,x.Count())` but whether the entire code works or not .... This is way more complicated that common EF Core code, for little (if any) benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function return type is not anonymous. It's tuple.
You can do this:

```
var items = (await context.ToListAsync<Job>(x => x
                                .Include(y => y.Status)))
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Status.StatusType)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x => (x.Key, x.Count()))
                            .ToList();

                return items;
```

Comment: @haim770 Thank you. I didn't know we can ignore the writing 'new Tuple' keyword in Linq. Just learned that. I am gonna try it next time I need it.

Comment: That's a C# 7.0 feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: @haim770 I knew that... I don't why I thought in Linq it's like old times :). Every place else I used it like you wrote.

Comment: Also, as @Heinzi pointed out, it's actually `ValueTuple` being emitted when using the new syntax (to avoid extra allocations)

Comment: Thank you all for the help, worked great. couldn't see the wood for the trees.